# Validate HTML input date tag using zod with React

Tags: reactjs, zod

Currently I have a React-application with a useState object. As the user enters a date into an `<input type="date" />`, it stores that value to the useState object.

I am trying to validate the input afterwards with Zod. But it fails since the input is stored as a string, and I am trying to validate the input as a date (`z.date()`).

Now, do I have to, if it's possible, convert the input from a string to a date? Or is it fine storing the date as a string and just change the validation to accept a string?

I guess it depends on how the database is supposed to work. Any tips/recommendations/thoughts on this? What would be your approach and what's the alternatives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the core of your question is asking how to use `zod` to parse a `Date` from a `string`, which the `zod` docs actually have an example for how to do [in the Dates section](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod#dates).

```js
const dateSchema = z.preprocess((arg) => {
  if (typeof arg == "string" || arg instanceof Date) return new Date(arg);
}, z.date());
```

Here they create a `dateSchema` that preprocesses the input to attempt to convert `string` inputs into `Date` objects before handing them into the `date` core schema.

If you have further restrictions, you can apply those to the `z.date()` call. (For example you could set a minimum or maximum date).

Answer (score 2):

Zod added a new functionality where you can force the parsing of the input to the specified type with `coerce` : https://zod.dev/?id=coercion-for-primitives

> Since *zod 3.20*, use `z.coerce.date()` to pass the input through `new Date(input)`.

```js
const dateSchema = z.coerce.date();
type DateSchema = z.infer<typeof dateSchema>;
// type DateSchema = Date

/* valid dates */
console.log(dateSchema.safeParse("2023-01-10T00:00:00.000Z").success); // true
console.log(dateSchema.safeParse("2023-01-10").success); // true
console.log(dateSchema.safeParse("1/10/23").success); // true
console.log(dateSchema.safeParse(new Date("1/10/23")).success); // true

/* invalid dates */
console.log(dateSchema.safeParse("2023-13-10").success); // false
console.log(dateSchema.safeParse("0000-00-00").success); // false
```

(source: https://zod.dev/?id=dates)